# Linux SED Command equal to string not contain

Tags: linux, sed

Currently having a problem with using SED command

For example:
I have 2 files

First file contain abc
Second file contain abcaaa

Sed command i am using

sed -i "s/'abc'/change/g"

However my result for both file turn out to be

first file : change
second file changeaaa

How do i make it only equal to abc and not contain abc?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/\babc\b/change/g' file
```

Comment: or `sed 's/^abc$/change/' file`

Comment: yep. (just for min character for comment)

Comment: You should mention that's GNU-specific.